# PHP: Undefined variable when assigning value to it with a ternary operator

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I am missing something. I'm sure is something stupid but I don't know what it is, sorry.

I am assinging a string to `$onClick` using a ternary operator.
Right after that, I try to access `$onClick` and I get `Undefined variable: onClick` error.

I have tried with simpler versions (booleans instead of strings) but it's the same. I also tried wrapping them with same result.

Apart from the example below (CakePHP), I created an online snippet [here](https://repl.it/@Hacheraw/Undefined-onCLick) replacing `debug()` with `var_dump()`. Note: to see notices on this console you have to fork it, but I assure you there are notices!

Note: trying to provide as much examples as I can, I may have complicated things. The line I have problems with is the one commented with this: `<--- this one`

**Code**:

```php
$id = 39; // just for this example
$isNew = true; // just for this example

// debug() examples:
debug($isNew); // line 42
debug($isNew ? "sendMeasure('add', null)" : "sendMeasure('edit', {$id})"); //42

// Actual problematic line:
$onCLick = $isNew ? "sendMeasure('add', null)" : "sendMeasure('edit', {$id})"; // <--- this one
debug($onClick); // line 47

// tying a simple bool value (just in case):
$onCLick = $isNew ? true : false;
debug($onClick); // line 51

// I even wrapped them (just in case):
$onCLick = ($isNew ? true : false);
debug($onClick); // line 55

// Expected behavior below:
if ($isNew) {
    $onClick = "sendMeasure('add', null)";
} else {
    $onClick = "sendMeasure('edit', {$id})";
}
debug($onClick); // line 63
```

**Output**:

[image: debug() output]

Comment: You're assigning the variable `$onCLick` but are debugging the variable `$onClick`.

Comment: You assign to "onCLick" note the upper L, and then you check "onClick" with lower "l". Fix this and this should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with uppercase and lowercase variable. variable defined as $onCLick and you checking as $onClick

```
// Actual problematic line:
$onClick = $isNew ? "sendMeasure('add', null)" : "sendMeasure('edit', {$id})"; // <--- this one
debug($onClick); // line 47

// tying a simple bool value (just in case):
$onClick = $isNew ? true : false;
debug($onClick); // line 51

// I even wrapped them (just in case):
$onClick = ($isNew ? true : false);
debug($onClick); // line 55
```

Comment: I new it was something... argh, shame on me